# ¿Por qué no se me imprime la variable hashes?

Tags: bash, curl

Estoy realizando un código en BASH y quiero imprimir por pantalla unos datos de una página web. A la hora de ejecutar el script y poner el parámetro menos -e más el nombre de la función me deja como resultado una línea vacía. ¿Por qué no consigue representar los hashes?

'''

```
function Unconfirmedtransactions()
{
   echo '' > ut.tmp 

   while [ "$(cat ut.tmp | wc -l)" == "1" ]; do 
      curl -s "$unconfirmed_transactions" | html2text > ut.tmp
   done 

   hashes=$(cat ut.tmp | grep "Hash" -A 1 | grep -v -E "Hash|\--|Time")

   echo $"Hash_Cantidad_Bitcoin_Tiempo" > ut.table 

   echo $hashes

   for hash in $hashes; do
     echo "${hash}" >> ut.table 
   done

   tput -T xterm-256color cnorm
}
```

'''

La lógica a conseguir es que exista un fichero con el nombre ut.tmp y que esté vacío, consiguiendo así con un while que si está vacío quiero que me lo rellene con el comando curl -s. No se si es esa la parte que falla.

Adjunto imagen

[image: Como véis me devuelve el fichero en blanco]

Comment: donde defines `$undefined_transactions`? en tu codigo no se ve esta variable en ningun sitio definida.

Comment: ¿has mirado si `$hashes` tiene valor? Sería bueno simplificar el ejemplo para ir a la raíz del problema, veo mucho código pero lo esencial apendas deben ser 2-3 líneas.

Comment: unconfirmed_transactions="https://www.blockchain.com/es/btc/unconfirmed-transactions"

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo ver si hashes tiene valor?